# Disabling automatic inheritance for Member type relationship

Tags: civimember

One of our client would like to use the CiviMember module to setup memberships for organisation they work with. They offer a subscription service where an organisation is a member and as part of that membership 5 users can access specific content on the website.

Reading through the document I see that this can easily be setup. However, the issue is that the client would like to have an approval workflow process instead of just allowing people to signup from the front end of the site and get automatically attached to an organisation i.e. the client would like to verify the person signing up for the organisation membership before allowing them to access information on the site.

In the CiviBook it says *Use this field to configure Membership Types where memberships are automatically granted to related contacts*. However, we would like to stop memberships being automatically granted.

I tried the option of not assigning a relationship type to the Membership option but then the Max related option disappears. Is there any way to stop this from automatically happening or am I missing something in the setup.

This is a Drupal 7 website using CiviCRM 4.6.11.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Might this be a question of which Relationship you are using this on. Eg you could create a new Relationship Type of 'associate of' to link the individual to the organisation.

When individuals sign up, they get the usual 'employee of' relationship. And then the admins for the client can 'verify' by also giving that contact an 'associate of' Relationship

Comment: Hi Pete. Thanks for the reply. However, in this scenario would the person signing up still automatically get associated with the organisation? Or are you suggesting we replace the profile field to have another field called Associate of or whatever text we choose and then allow people to sign up to join that membership. The admin will then go in an verify the user and manually attach the user to the organisation?

Comment: Hard to know what workflow you currently have. You could have a Profile that individuals sign up for, which adds them as 'employee of' to the Organisation. Then when you have 'verified' them you could add the 'associate of' Relationship as well, which will cause them to inherit the Membership